Collision not working properly between rects in Pygame
I have a variable, colliding, that should check if two rects are colliding. The collision works fine most of the time, but when trying to check if the rects are NOT colliding, the if statement passes regardless of if they are actually colliding. After some logging, I discovered that the collision statement returns False most of the time, but returns True about 1 in 5 frames if the rects are colliding. I double checked that my rects are actually colliding, and are formatted properly.
Here is the relevant code:
colliding = pygame.Rect(self.objRect).colliderect(pygame.Rect(player.rect))
if player.jumping:
    player.jumpTimer += 1
    if player.jumpTimer >= 60:
        if not colliding:
            player.jumping = False
            player.jumpTimer = 0
        else:
            #logic that is running when it shouldn't




Welcome to StackOverflow.  While you have provided some code example for others to attempt to identify the issue, the actual issue cannot be reproduced.  Please provide additional context and/or minimum amount of code that will actually reproduce the issue at hand. That being said, colliding is simply a boolean value and you can help yourself by logging that value and then logging the execution of if not colliding: block, and ideally include this log with the minimum amount of code that can reproduce this issue, otherwise it would be impossible for others to discover your exact problem.
